# Realm - Is there a way to release objects from RealmResults after processing?

Tags: android, out-of-memory, realm

I have to restore my view data from `ContentCache`.

There are up to 300 records. Each of them is a huge json format string(lengh > 86400).

I always get a `OOM` while it's restoring it.

```
RealmResults<ContentCache> result = realmHelper.getContentCacheService(realm).listAll(realm);

for( ContentCache cache : result ){
    refreshContentPage(cache);
}
```

or

```
int size = realmHelper.getContentCacheService(realm).size(realm);

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    ContentCache cache = realmHelper.getContentCacheService(realm).get(realm, i);
    refreshContentPage(cache);
}
```

Both of them will throw an OOM when I restore it at the 2nd time.

How can I avoid this exception?

Comment: you should use  realmHelper.close();

Comment: What are these methods? What does `listAll()` do for example? What is `refreshContentPage`?

Comment: What does `realmHelper.getContentCacheService` do?

Comment: `listAll()` is doing `realm.where(ENTITY_CLASS).findAll()`. And `getContentCacheService` is getting a class which handles all the database operations. `refreshContentPage()` is parsing the json and restoring the datas to my recyclerView. I put the `realm.close()` in the `onStop()` of my Fragment. And `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` is in the `onStart()`. Should I call `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` and close it every time?

Comment: Do you manipulate the objects inside the loop? Usually it happens when you try to delete a realm obj inside a loop.
However check your fragment lifecycle, maybe it calls onStop() too soon. In this case you should review your business logic and consider the operations to perform when the connection abort

Comment: No, I just get the json string from the RealmObject, like, `cache.getJson()`. Do you mean that if there is a `realm.executeTransactionAsync()` still running, I shoud not call `realm.close()` before it's done? So if I want to use `realm.executeTransactionAsync()`, it's better to get instance and close it every time?

Comment: You should move Fragment's Realm create/close to `onCreateView()`/`onDestroyView()` respectively

Comment: But I'm following the best practice which is described here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances. Do you mean it's wrong?

Comment: 300 objects, each with a string of 160 KB (two bytes per character): about 50 MB. Depending on your device, 50 MB can be a large fraction of the total memory.

Comment: Yes. That's why I'm wondering if there's a way to release it from memory. And another question is that they are the same objects, the memory usage should not be increased when I call `findAll()` again.